# IntelliJ v14, how to bring up a method parameters information via keyboard or mouse input?

Tags: intellij-idea, parameters, keyboard-shortcuts

I really like how IntelliJ displays the information of the type of parameters that you are required to fill in as you are writing the code. The problem is that this info sometimes disappears if u click somewhere to check something etc. I never quite know how to get it to display that information again in same fashion. So I always spend some time to fiddle around until it displays that info again in the same fashion. I know you can hold down on ctrl and hover over the method name to bring up parameters information but its not quite the same and it then does not highlight on what parameter you are currently on. IntelliJ also brings up required parameters type of information when you are starting to go wrong. It brings up this big separate box and you can get very clear view of what needs to be done. I've taken a screenshot of the type of information that I'm on about. Both of them are on the same pic.

[Please check it out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lmpm.png)

My question: is there a way to bring this information up via keystrokes or mouse input at will? I've tried to google for an answer but I haven't had any joy. Please advise as I'm sure someone else might like this information too.
Thank you.

PS. I know that a good code does not usually have that many parameters but in my case there is not much that can be done.

Comment: View | Parameter Info (Ctrl+P). IntelliJ IDEA 2016+ also has the new parameter hints feature.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - This is exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm. Thank you.
Does anyone know if there is also a way to bring up the required parameters in a table format like on the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Default shortcut for that is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> when cursor is inside the brackets.